# pass the event and the element to the handler via event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to attach keypress event listener to each of `words` dom elements and pass the element itself ( I mean `word`) to the `eventHandler`  ok?

So I tried this but it seems that I lose the event itself:

```
const eventHandler = (e, word) => {
    console.log('keypressed', String.fromCharCode(e.which), word);
}

words.forEach((word) => {
    window.addEventListener("keypress", eventHandler.bind(event, word));
});
```

`String.fromCharCode(e.which)` should bring the pressed key on keyboard but it returns nothing!!

How can I fix this?

Edit:

Here is the simpler reproduction of the issue: press any key on the keyboard and see the event is undefined:

```js
const eventHandler = (event, word) => {
    console.log('keypressed', event, word);
}
window.addEventListener("keypress", eventHandler.bind(this, event, 'word'));
```

Comment: The first parameter of `bind()` is the `this` value, with each successive parameter being arguments passed to the function being bound.

Comment: even with first parameter of `this` the `e` in the `eventHandler` is still `undefined`

Comment: The event is implicitly passed, and will be the last parameter after all the bound parameters. So `eventHandler.bind(null, word)` and then the handler should be called `eventHandler(word, e)`

Comment: Can you add some HTML to your question as a [mcve] so we can help you debug this? At the moment it's hard to see where these `words` fits in to all this.

Comment: Yeah I think this works... Answer will be accepted to this...

Comment: @ Andy  JavaScript really needs to be revised in 2021...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event is implicitly passed, and will be the last parameter after all the bound parameters.

So you would use `eventHandler.bind(null, word)` and then the handler should be declared `eventHandler(word, e) {...}`

```js
const button = document.getElementById('b');

function handler(bound_arg, event){
  console.log(event.target);
  console.log(bound_arg);
}

button.addEventListener('click', handler.bind(null,'bound'));
```

```html
<button type='button' id='b'>Bound</button>
```

But this isn't very intuitive, and since `bind()` creates a new function anyway you could simply use an anonymous function to pass the word.

```
window.addEventListener("keypress", (e) => eventHandler(e, word));
```

Comment: Is there any difference to remove the lister here?

Comment: Both of them suffer problems removing the listener as they both create new functions. In both cases you would need to store a reference to each function to facilitate removal. This might be a good case for event delegation.

Comment: Please have a look at the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69242724/remove-event-listeners-with-extra-arguments