# remove event listeners with extra arguments

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the event listener I'm using:

```
const eventHandler = (word, e) => {
    if(isAnimating && duplicates.includes(word.innerHTML)) return; 
    if(String.fromCharCode(e.which) == word.innerHTML && !distWords.includes(word)) {
        move(word);
    } 
}
words.forEach(word => {
    window.addEventListener("keypress", eventHandler.bind(null, word));
});
```

The issue is I'm unable to remove the listener, I used something like this with no luck:

```
removeIT = () => {
        words.forEach(word => {
            window.removeEventListener("keypress", eventHandler.bind(null, word));
        }); 
}
```

How can I remove the listers effectivly?

Comment: When you use bind you’re [creating a new function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind), so you can’t remove the event listener just by referencing the `eventHandler` function. With the use of arrow functions there’s really no reason to use `bind` in your case: moreover you are never referencing `this` anyway.

Comment: So what do you recommend?

Comment: What is `word`? Can you show us your markup? See how to create a [mcve]. There might be ways to refer to the element without needing to pass it as an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to continue with this pattern you will need to store references to each bound function and iterate over them to remove the listeners.

```
const words_listeners = [];

words.forEach(word => {
    const handler = eventHandler.bind(null, word);
    window.addEventListener("keypress", handler);
    words_listeners.push(handler);
});  

removeIT = () => {
    words_listeners.forEach(handler => {
        window.removeEventListener("keypress", handler);
    }); 
}
```

The snippet below is attaching `click` listeners to buttons, so it is necessary to also store the element that the listener is attached to, but in your case, since you're attaching to the window, you won't need to. Basically, in the loop in which you are attaching the listeners, create your bound function and assign it to a variable, attach your listener with it, then push it to an array which can be used to remove the listeners later.

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.word')
const word_listeners = [];

const eventHandler = (word, e) => {
    console.log(word)
}

buttons.forEach(button => {
    const handler = eventHandler.bind(null, button.textContent);
    button.addEventListener('click', handler);
    word_listeners.push([button, handler]);
}); 

function remove_listeners() {
  word_listeners.forEach(([button, handler]) => button.removeEventListener('click', handler));
}

document.getElementById('remove').addEventListener('click', remove_listeners);
```

```html
<button type="button" class="word">One</button>
<button type="button" class="word">Two</button>
<button type="button" class="word">Three</button>

<button type="button" id="remove">Remove listeners</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it needs to be that complicated. If you call a function that returns a closure that acts the listener you don't need any binding.

I've had to use buttons here because I don't know what your markup is like.

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

function handleClick() {
  console.log(this);
}

function removeAllListeners(buttons) {
  buttons.forEach(button => {
    button.disabled = true;
    button.removeEventListener('click', handleClick);
  });
}

function handler(word) {
  console.log(word);
  return handleClick;
}

buttons.forEach(button => {
  const { textContent } = button;
  button.addEventListener('click', handler(textContent), false);
});

setTimeout(removeAllListeners, 5000, buttons);
```

```css
button { background-color: #efefef; cursor: pointer; }
button:disabled { background-color: #ffb3b3; cursor: default; }
```

```html
<button>Tree</button>
<button>Giant</button>
<button>Billy Joel</button>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of removing the listeners later, and since handler returns a new function on each call it will require a similar solution that bind would