# How do I remove an event listener on an event that uses an arrow function

Tags: javascript, events, addeventlistener, removeeventlistener

This is my example code:

```
    let element = document.getElementById("element")
    element.addEventListener("click", (ev)=>{
    console.log("this is where I would remove the event listener")
    })
```

I tried trying to find tutorials and websites telling me how to but none of them actually worked.`

Comment: You are going to have to put it into a variable

Comment: also: [Removing event listener which was added with bind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11565471/removing-event-listener-which-was-added-with-bind) or  [remove event listeners with extra arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69242724/remove-event-listeners-with-extra-arguments/69243303#69243303)

Comment: `for (handler of getEventListeners(document.getElementById("element"))) document.getElementById("element").removeEventListener('click', handler)`

Comment: Isn't it an option that you give the function a name, for example `element.addEventListener("click", function example() { ... })`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Dec/2022 there are no native JavaScript methods that can be used to get event handlers that were added through `.addEventListener`.  The most convenient way to do this is to simply keep a reference to your function:

```
let handler = (ev) => console.log("this is where I would remove the event listener")
let element = document.getElementById("element")
element.addEventListener("click", handler)
```

Then remove it:

```
element.removeEventListener("click", handler)
```

There are ways to obtain some event handlers like `getEventListeners()`, however they not part of the DOM specification and support is limited.